# Migrating Specific SVN Revisions from Server A to Server B

Tags: svn, migration

I have migrated a SVN Repository from Server A (servera.example.com) to Server B (serverb.example.com). Server A & Server B do not have a direct connectivity. The SVN Repository Dump from Server A has to been copied to an FTP Server and then Server B had copied the Dump and imported. Now at this stage, Server A and  Server B has the same number of revisions both the sides (28700)..

As part of testing, in ServerB SVN Repo, few commits has been made (i.e 50 new commits) and now the total revisions in ServerB Repository is 28750.. At this point, developers are still using repository in Server A and the total revisions had reached to 28975 (i.e 275 new  commits).. And Server A  repository had been set to read only mode and the revisions from 28701-28975 has to be exported and imported in SVN Server B.. How can we achieve this?

**Note:** The few commits which has been in  Server B Repository can be deleted (28700-28750) as we don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `svnadmin dump` (or `svnrdump`) with `--incremental`. I think the following should work:

```
svnadmin dump -r 28700:HEAD --incremental svn.servera > servera_incr.dump
svnadmin load svn.serverb < servera_incr.dump
```

Comment: But I guess this will have a merge conflict issue. I don't think so, there is an official way to delete the revisions.

Comment: Yes, merge conflicts are possible - but you wrote: "The few commits which has been in Server B Repository can be deleted"